# I want to display data in second select box when i select first select box from API url json data

Tags: html, forms, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I have json file in assets/file.json.I used reactive form method.I Want to display details(only name) in a second drop down while selecting department.I have already displayed the dept in first drop down.but nothing seeing in second drop down.

```
[
    {
        "DEPT": "PHYSICS",
        "details": [
        {
            "id": 164,
            "name": "A",


        },
        {
            "id": 265,
            "name": "B",

        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DEPT": "BIOLOGY",
        "details": [
        {
            "id": 155,
            "name": "C",

        },
        {
            "id": 234,
            "name": "D",

        }
        ]
    }
]
```

What i did is ...

first drop down 
....................

```
<select  formControlName="dept">
                      <option value="default">--Select a dept--</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let d of departments$" [value]="d.DEPT"> {{d.DEPT}} </option>
                  </select>
```

second drop down
......................

```
<select formControlName="details">
              <option value="0">--All--</option> 
     <option *ngFor="let d of dept.value" [value]="d.details.name"> {{d.details.name}} </option> -->
          </select>
```

I want to display when i select dept biology,second drop down should show the names C,D.

Comment: Ok. But there's no question here. Is something not working as intended? If so, what errors are produced in the console?

Comment: even dept  first select box showing nothing.. showing in console  ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: You need to use `*ngIf` to hide the `details` select until the `dept` select has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just write a basic code snippet for your required functionality. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<select (change)="checkDepart($event.target.value)">
  <option value="default">--Select a dept--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index" [value]="i"> {{d.DEPT}} </option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="visibleDetail">
  <option value="0">--All--</option> 
  <option *ngFor="let d of data[selectedDept].details" [value]="d.name"> {{d.name}} </option> 
</select>
```

**TS**

```
visibleDetail: boolean;
selectedDept: number;

data = [
  {
     "DEPT": "PHYSICS",
     "details": [
        {
           "id": 164,
           "name": "A",
        }, {
            "id": 265,
            "name": "B",
        }
      ]
 }, {
    "DEPT": "BIOLOGY",
    "details": [
       {
           "id": 155,
           "name": "C",
       }, {
           "id": 234,
           "name": "D",
       }
        ]
    }
]

checkDepart(e) {
  this.visibleDetail = true;
  this.selectedDept = e;
}
```